# Multiple sources for AudioContext()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I have two one-second audio sources as follows:

```
var context = system.AudioContext();
var source = context.createBufferSource();

var audioBuffer1 = context.createBuffer(1, float32Array_1.length, context.sampleRate);
audioBuffer1.getChannelData(0).set(float32Array_1);

var audioBuffer2 = context.createBuffer(1, float32Array_2.length, context.sampleRate);
audioBuffer2.getChannelData(0).set(float32Array_2);
```

Now I want to play these two audio sources with no delay between them. For a single source I can play the audio with the following code:

```
source.buffer = audioBuffer1;
source.connect(context.destination);
source.start(0);
```

How can I attach the second source such that there would be no delay between them.

Comment: Is the idea that you want to play them *simultaneously*, or that you want them to play *sequentially* ?

Comment: The idea is to play them sequentially with no glitch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var context = system.AudioContext();
var source = context.createBufferSource();
var source2 = context.createBufferSource();

var audioBuffer1 = context.createBuffer(1, float32Array_1.length, context.sampleRate);
audioBuffer1.getChannelData(0).set(float32Array_1);

var audioBuffer2 = context.createBuffer(1, float32Array_2.length, context.sampleRate);
audioBuffer2.getChannelData(0).set(float32Array_2);

source.buffer = audioBuffer1;
source.connect(context.destination);

source2.buffer = audioBuffer2;
source2.connect(context.destination);

var time = context.currentTime;

source.start(time);
source2.start(time+audioBuffer1.duration);
```

Comment: Thanks. Works great. Just to make it a little bit more comprehensive, please replace `time + 1` to `time + audioBuffer1.duration`